# Can we use Uploadify simply for progressive enhancement on file upload inputs?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

When I do file inputs, I usually set their `opacity` to 0 and position a `browse` button beneath them (simply because the file inputs are kind of ugly and inflexible by themselves - and I must to meet the designer's requirements).

I just stumbled across [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

My form is working at the moment as a standard form with file input uploads.

I wish to use Uploadify just for the features...

- Forcing the upload prompt to an extension (`jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, `gif`).
- Showing the filename once selected and filesize

I set the option to not upload automatically on selection.

When I submit the form now with this jQuery invocation code...

```
var fileTypes = [];
$.each(config.validExt, function(i, ext) {
 fileTypes.push('*.' + ext);
});

var fileInputs = form.find('input[type=file]');

fileInputs.uploadify({
'uploader'  : config.basePath + 'assets/packages/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : config.basePath + 'assets/packages/uploadify/uploadify.php',
'cancelImg' : config.basePath + 'assets/packages/uploadify/cancel.png',
'auto'      : false,
'folder'    : config.basePath + 'application/uploads',
'fileDesc'  : 'Images (' + config.validExt.join(', ') + ')' ,
'fileExt'   : fileTypes.join(';')
});

form.find('button[type=submit]').click(function(event) {

fileInputs.uploadifyUpload();

});
```

It just falls over and doesn't upload anything.

Also, sending the `folder` from the client sounds a little flaky, but I planned to select the folder via PHP.

So basically, I want the form to act like usual, just to have those benefits from using Uploadify.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is. I've used Uploadify in few projects and it's a bit tricky to use but once you get it working it's a nicer way of uploading stuff and users appreciate it. But I don't think you can make it work exactly as a HTML input type="file" field. To debug why it is not working, log the contents of POST in your PHP script. It is possible you might have to use absolute or relative path to the script (with preceding "/").

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the form via the onAllComplete option.  Make sure the button is not a submit button.

```
fileInputs.uploadify({
  'uploader'      : config.basePath + 'assets/packages/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
  'script'        : config.basePath + 'assets/packages/uploadify/uploadify.php',
  'cancelImg'     : config.basePath + 'assets/packages/uploadify/cancel.png',
  'auto'          : false,
  'folder'        : config.basePath + 'application/uploads',
  'fileDesc'      : 'Images (' + config.validExt.join(', ') + ')' ,
  'fileExt'       : fileTypes.join(';'),
  'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
      form.submit();
    }
});

form.find('#submit').click(function(event) {
  fileInputs.uploadifyUpload();
});
```